# Reason for dip in flink performance in streaming

Tags: hadoop, spark-streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Currently we are using spark with 1 minute batch interval to process the data. The data flow is like HTTP endpoint -> Spring XD -> kafka -> Spark Streaming -> HBASE. Format is JSON. We are running the spark jobs in a environment which has 6 nodemanagers each with 16 CPU cores and 110 GB of RAM. For caching metedata scala's triemap is used,so the cache will be per executor. Results on Spark with below settings:

```
Kafka partitions - 45
Spark executors - 3
Cores per executor -15
Number of JSON records 455 000 received over a time of 10 minutes.
```

Spark processed the records in 12 minutes. And each executor is able to process about 350-400 records per sec. Json parsing, validations, other stuffs are done before loading into HBASE.

With almost the same code with modifications for flink I ran the code with flink streaming deployed in YARN cluster. Results on Flink with below settings:

```
Kafka partitions - 45
Number of Task Managers for running the job - 3
Slots per TM - 15
Parallelism  - 45
Number of JSON records 455 000 received over a time of 10 minutes.
```

But flink takes almost 50 minutes to process the records. With each TM process 30-40 records per second.

What am i missing here? Are there any other parameters/Configurations apart from the mentioned one impacts performance? The Job flow is DataStream -> Map -> custom functions. How could I improve the performance of flink here?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in details, what the streaming job is doing?
How are you writing the data into Hbase? (Maybe it makes sense to do a test run without the HBase sink, to see if there's an issue with the hbase connector)

Comment: The main parts in the streaming job are getting message from Kafka, decompressing and parsing the JSON, getting all the required information from metadata available in HBASE, metadata validation, forming a put list to insert some 8-10 columns, finally inserting into HBASE.

Comment: Thanks. I would run a test without HBASE sink and share the results.

Comment: Is the implementation of the "getting metadata from HBASE" part the same in Flink and Spark?
I suspect that something in the Flink implementation is different, slowing everything down.

Comment: The whole code  is same for spark and flink except the one required for flink to kick start streaming.Once the metadata is fetched from HBASE it is cached in JVM by triemap. So out of 4.55 lakh records the metadata would be fetched only for first 500 records from HBASE in all 3 task managers. The data is repeatedly sent only for those 500 record combination only the original value and timestamp differs.

Comment: Okay, I see. So the data is basically cached, and the performance impact is negligible after the first few hundred records.

Comment: It seems like creating hbase connections seems to be a overhead. In spark a connection is created for every RDD partition inside foreachpartition. What and where we have to initialize the connections in flink for optimal performance?

Comment: I would open the HBase connection once in the open() method.

Comment: What would that mean, one connection for a thread and that being reused? And is there a Scala snippet available for the writehbase streaming example. https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-batch-connectors/flink-hbase/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/addons/hbase/example/HBaseWriteStreamExample.java

Comment: I constructed a Scala code with that java code and the result looks promising. I will update you once I run the same test with the main code.

Comment: When converting spark code to flink, not sure how to optimize the reads.Could you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262790/how-to-read-and-write-to-hbase-in-flink-streaming-job